# Question on tensor product with field

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $K$-algebra which has no zero divisors. Here $K$ is a field of characteristic $0$. Let $K\subset L$ an algebraic field extension. Now let $f: L\to E$ and $g: \textrm{Quot}(A)\to E$ be two homomorphisms to another field $E$. The universal property of the tensor product gives us a homomorphism $A\otimes_K L \to E$. Is this necessarily injective?

Comment: Is it of any importance that $g$ is $\operatorname{Quot} A → E$ and not simply $A → E$?

Comment: I also could have required an *injective* map $A\to E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ℂ \otimes_ℝ ℂ → ℂ,~x\otimes y ↦ xy$ is not injective, since $1^2 + \mathrm i^2 = 0$.